# Generar Un solo Voto por votante

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php5

Tengo tres tablas:

1. Aspirante
2. Votante
3. Resultado

Ya logro que se haga el voto, lo que no logro es que un votante pueda votar solo una sola vez y si sigue intentando con un alert muestre que ya voto.  De esta forma logro que se realice el voto:

```
$voto = $voto + 1;
$consulta2 = " UPDATE resultados SET voto = $voto WHERE id_res = '$id_asp' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
```

Comment: Requieres JS para el alter, por otro lado requieres hacer un count a la tabla donde se almacena el voto registrado basándote en el id del votante

Comment: recomiendo normalizar la base de datos para que quede un registro de voto

Comment: Una pregunta, tu sistema es con usuarios, es decir para poder votar necesitas que un usuario se autentique o puede votar cualquier persona sin necesidad de hacer una cuenta.

Comment: si la persona que va a votar entra con un usuario y clave

Comment: @KevinDelva no técnicamente sino funcionalmente, uno no debería tener registro de voto por usuario. Debería haber registro de usuarios que ya votaron y en otra tabla, las "papeletas" donde cada registro es un voto por un aspirante.

Comment: @MICO significa entonces que no se puede hacer reconteo porque no hay registro individual de cada voto? Que, si hay algún error y suma mal, no hay cómo saberlo?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo el siguiente diagrama para tu modelo de datos:

[image: Diagrama relacional propuesto]

Que puedes obtener con este código:

```
CREATE TABLE aspirantes(
  id_aspirante int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  aspirante varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE votantes(
  id_votante int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_aspirante int,
  votante varchar(31),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_aspirante) REFERENCES aspirantes(id_aspirante)
  );
```

Por el propio diseño de la base de datos un votante no podrá votar a más de un aspirante y, para contar los votos de cada aspirante, puedes utilizar esta consulta:

```
SELECT id_aspirante,COUNT(*) votos
  FROM votantes
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Crear una tabla para almacenar los resultados de lo que debería ser un dato calculado, salvo contadas excepciones, no es la mejor opción.

**Integración en diseño existente**

Si puedes añadir un campo a la tabla `votantes`, ni lo dudes:

```
ALTER TABLE votantes ADD id_aspirante INT;
```

Para controlar que no se vote más de una vez, tendrías que registrar en algún sitio quién ha votado ya, y ésta es la solución más sencilla que vas a encontrar.

No entiendo lo de "pagar donde se realiza el voto" pero, al igual que almacenas a quién se vota en `votantes`, también puedes guardar ahí mismo desde dónde se vota.

Si no puedes tocar esas tablas, entonces cuéntanos tus restricciones, a ver cómo podemos soslayarlas...

Comment: amigo de antemano muchas gracias por la respuesta. Pero como lo adaptaría si yo tengo creada la BD con tres tablas  aspirante (Id_aspirante, nombre) votante(id_votantante,nombres,usuario,clave) resultado(id_resultado,voto,id_aspirante)....  La tabla votante solo la tomo en mi bd para que pueda ingresar con clave y usuario al form_votar.php (pagan donde se realiza el voto) y la tabla resultado que es donde relaciono el voto que ademas se inicializa en cero(0) y por eso es que hago un UPDATE para que se va actualizando y esta es la que esta relacionada con la tabla aspirante

Comment: Ok, amplío la respuesta para intentar solventar tus dudas... déjame los comentarios que necesites para aclararlo

Comment: Sres. Había quedado sin pc pero pero ya lo retome. Les cuento q aun sigo intentando un solo voto por cada persona que se registra con login. pero aun no logro. el voto omo lo dije al inicio si logro actualizarlo por que parte de cero(0) y va sumando de uno en uno pero no logro que después de votar un electo no pueda seguirlo haciendo.cree otra tabla votante-aspirante con los campos id_votante, id_aspirante pero no logro que se inserta hay el registro (intento hacer un inser into a la tabla votante-aspirante pero no se porque no se inerta el registrao en el campo id-votante e id_aspirante )

Comment: Bienvenido de vuelta @MICO, te sugiero que plantees una nueva pregunta aportando el fragmento de código que quieres que revisemos y la base de datos en SQL (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) para que podamos reproducir lo que pretendes hacer. También te doy la posibilidad de darte instrucciones a través de una videollamada contactando conmigo a través de LinkedIn, mi cuenta está en mi perfil.